# Calculate $\int x^2\sqrt{a^2+x^2}dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

> Calculate $$\int x^2\sqrt{a^2+x^2}dx$$

My try (directly integrating by parts): $$\int x^2\sqrt{a^2+x^2}=\dfrac{x^3}{3}\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-\int \dfrac{x^3}{3}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} dx=\\=\dfrac{x^3}{3}\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-\dfrac13\int \dfrac{x^3\cdot x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx=\\=\dfrac{x^3}{3}\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-\dfrac13\int x^3d\sqrt{x^2+a^2}.$$ How do we calculate this (new) integral though?

P.S.  I am not yet familiar with the approach that uses substitution for solving integrals, so I'd rather integrate by parts on this occasion (as I think it would probably work).

Comment: Just like the integral you previously posed, this one can also be handled by substitution (IBP is, in a way, a form of substitution, so it would be beneficial to look into it). I think parts alone won't clear this, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Instead of this integration by parts, I would perform the substitution $x=a\frac u{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$, to reduce to the integration of a rational function.

Comment: if you are not familiar with any substitution (or change of variable), then follow what you did, you can continue $\int \frac{1}{3}\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} dx = \frac{I}{3} - a^2 \frac{1}{3}(\int \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} - a^2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}})$, $I$ is your target integral.

Comment: I am going to strongly urge you to read on substitution, as it can make integrals of this type easy to do. I haven't been able to proceed with a "parts-only" solution. Substitution is usually taught before integration by parts, and uses similar thinking. With that said, try $x = a \tan u.$

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it via hyperbolic substitution plus integration by parts (it'd be too cumbersome to work only with IBP).

We begin by doing $x=a\sinh\theta$, thus $dx=a\cosh\theta d\theta$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal J\equiv\int x^2\sqrt{a^2+x^2}dx&=\int a^2\sinh^2\theta\sqrt{a^2+a^2\sinh^2\theta}\ a\cosh\theta d\theta\\
&=a^4\int\sinh^2\theta\cosh^2\theta d\theta\\
&=\dfrac{a^4}{4}\int\sinh^22\theta d\theta.
\end{aligned}$$

Now we proceed with IBP in order to compute $\int\sinh^22\theta d\theta$.

We choose $u=\sinh2\theta$ and $dv=\sinh2\theta d\theta$, meaning that $du=2\cosh\theta d\theta$ and that $v=\frac{1}{2}\cosh2\theta \ (+C)$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{4}{a^4}\mathcal J=\mathcal I=\int\sinh^22\theta d\theta&=\frac{1}{2}\sinh 2\theta\cosh2\theta-\int\cosh^22\theta d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sinh 2\theta\cosh2\theta-\int(1+\sinh^22\theta)d\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sinh 2\theta\cosh2\theta-\theta-\mathcal I
\end{aligned}$$
$$\implies \mathcal I=\frac{1}{2}\sinh 2\theta\cosh2\theta-\theta-\mathcal I$$
$$\hspace{0.5cm}\implies\mathcal I=\frac{1}{4}\sinh 2\theta\cosh2\theta-\frac{\theta}{2}.$$

At last we revert the substitution expressing $\theta$ in function of $x$ $\left(\theta=\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right)$. Thus, the final result should be
$$\mathcal J=\frac{a^4}{16}\sinh\left[2\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right]\cosh\left[2\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right]-\frac{a^4}{8}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C.$$

(Maybe it can be further simplified in the form of radicals?)

Comment: Wolfram alpha outputs a few simplified forms of it https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+a%5E4%2F16+sinh%282+arcsinh%28x%2Fa%29%29+cosh%282+arcsinh%28x%2Fa%29%29+-+a%5E4%2F8+arcsinh%28x%2Fa%29

Answer (score 0):

Among substitutions, hyperbolic one may be simpler.

WLOG, let’s put $x=a\sinh \theta$ where $a>0$, then the integral is transformed into
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int a^2 \sinh ^2 \theta \cdot a \cosh \theta \cdot a \cosh \theta d \theta \\
& =a^4 \int(\sinh \theta \cosh \theta)^2 d \theta \\
& =\frac{a^4}{4} \int \sinh ^2 2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{a^4}{4} \int \frac{\cosh 4 \theta-1}{2} d \theta \\
& =\frac{a^4}{8}\left(\frac{\sinh 4 \theta}{4}-\theta\right)+C \\
& =\frac{a^4}{8}(\sinh \theta \cosh \theta \cosh 2 \theta-\theta)+C \\
& =\frac{a^4}{8}\left[\frac{x}{a} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{a} \cdot\left(\frac{a^2+2 x^2}{a^2}\right)-\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right]+C\\& =\frac{1}{8}\left[x \sqrt{a^2+x^2}\left(a^2+2 x^2\right)-a^4 \sinh^{-1} \left(\frac xa\right)\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts twice as follows

\begin{align}
\int x^2\sqrt{a^2+x^2}\ dx
=& \int \frac{x}{4 \sqrt{a^2+x^2}}d[(a^2+x^2)^2]\\
\overset{ibp}=&\ \frac x4(a^2+x^2)^{\frac 32}-\frac{a^2}4 \int \sqrt{a^2+x^2}\ dx\\ 
 \int \sqrt{a^2+x^2}\ dx
=& \int \frac{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{2x}d(x^2)\\
\overset{ibp}=&\ \frac x2 \sqrt{a^2+x^2}+\frac{a^2}2 \int \frac1{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\ dx\\
 =&\ \frac x2 \sqrt{a^2+x^2}+\frac{a^2}2\sinh^{-1}\frac xa
\end{align}